# How can I compare two Lists against each other and set the pixels values accordingly using C#?

Tags: c#, image, list

I have two lists, List1 which contains the coordinate (x,y) of every pixel in my image “bmp”, and also List2 which contains integer values between 0,1,2,3,4 and 5. In which 0 represents the least significant bit (0) and 5 represents the most significant bit (255). 0 to 255 are the different level of grey colour.

My question is basically how can I compare List1 against List2 and set the pixel values in my image “bmp” according to the information from List2;

So the output will be a greyscale image which the colour of every pixel in the image is chosen according to my List2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a simple loop and multiplication to do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list2.Count; i++)
{
    int c = list2[i] * 51;
    bmp.SetPixel(list1[i].X, list1[i].Y, Color.FromArgb(c,c,c));
}
```

This will create a color based on the value in `list2`, and then set the color of the corresponding pixel (assuming that `list1`'s locations correspond to `list2`'s values).
Let me know if this helps.

Comment: could you please give me a bit more explanation, why are you multiplying [i] by 51? also what doeas (c,c,c) means? thanks;)

Comment: `int c = list2[i] * 51;` takes the value in list2 at index `i` and multiplies that by 51 to get the value you want (0=0, 1=51, 2=102, etc). This is basically a shortcut so that you con't have to write `if (list2[i] == 0)...else if (list2[i]==1)...` The `Color.FromArgb(c,c,c)` creates a color from the integer `c`, which is the value from list2 normalized as a color. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cce5h557(v=vs.110).aspx Let me know if anything else is unclear.

Comment: thank you for your comment, as i am making only grey-scale image, do i still need to work with RGB values?

Comment: As long as the RGB values are equal, the image will be grey. But yes, you will have to work with the RGB values since that's the basic building blocks of bitmaps. For the code I posted, the image will always be in a grey as long as you have `Color.FromArgb(c,c,c)` (since the R,G,and B parameters are equal). Let me know if you need anything else, or if this helped. :)

Comment: it just giving me error:  Error 1 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>' does not contain a definition for 'Length' and no extension method 'Length' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Error 2 Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>'

Comment: another error please: Error- 1 Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'method group'

Comment: yes it is. and one inside the for loop; Error2 Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>'

Comment: If you have parenthesis after count like `.Count()` removed those. as for the other errors, maybe you could google them or put your current code in your post.

Comment: thanks, but i just put what you gave me, nothing more;)

Comment: Ok, hopefully it helped. Sorry for any confusion. Good luck!

Comment: i think i found my mistake; i have used variable instead of list:    `var list2= sumOfAllFour.Zip(image5, (x, y) => x + y);`    what should i do instead?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know enough from that code snippet to help you. You could ask a new question, or google it.

Answer (score 0):

Try a for loop over the list, treating it like an array.

```
for (int i=0, i < list1.count-1, i++)
{
  switch (list2[i])
  {
    # Making a fake method here - I'm basically faking that the SetPixel method
    # takes in a coordinate and lets you set a value on that coordinate.
    case 1:
      bmp.Setpixel(list1[i]).value = 0;
      break;
    case 2:
      bmp.Setpixel(list1[i]) value = 51;
      break;
    etc...
  }
}
```

Comment: how do you assign for example 51 to a color shade?

Comment: That depends entirely on how you're building your bitmap. I believe @davidsbro's answer is more complete in that regard.